# Regex for not aaa

Tags: regex

I need a regex, idealy with only [a-z] | (string) ^ . * ? that will only match strings not containing the sequence "aaa", thus "bu","aa7a"etc. are accepted and "paaaaarot","aaaac","umraaaaaa" and such are not. It's really giving me a headache, so I'd be grateful for help (with short description, so I can understand how the solution works).

Comment: sorry, didn't find that one myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a negative lookahead -

```
(?!.*aaa.*)
```

Not sure how to do it with only the primitives you suggest.

Comment: thanks anyways, way better than nothing!!!